Игрок скользит с наклоных поверхностей Unity 2D
Я задал Physics Material 2D, где Friction для игрока указан 0 для того, что бы игрок не прилипал ко стенам. Но после этого он начал соскальзовать с обычных наклонных поверхностях.
Как это выглядит: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UL0P0A24X-BPcC7L9ZPcFKec0D8AsNsM/view?usp=sharing
using Inspector;
using UnityEngine;

namespace FuturePast.CharacterSystem
{
    public class MoveState : CharacterState
    {
        [SerializeField, Range(0, 30)] private float _walkSpeed = 10f;
        [SerializeField, Range(0, 30)] private float _runSpeed = 20f;
        [SerializeField, Range(0, 20)] private float _acceleration = 10f;
        [SerializeField, Range(0, 20)] private float _decceleration = 10f;
        [SerializeField] Vector2 _cornerToClimb;
        [SerializeField, ReadOnlyInspector] public float direction;
        [SerializeField, ReadOnlyInspector] public TypeMove typeMove = TypeMove.Walk;
        [SerializeField, ReadOnlyInspector] private float _moveSpeed;
        private Vector2 _normal;

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            Move();
        }

        private void Move()
        {
            _moveSpeed = GetSpeed();
            float targetSpeed = direction * _moveSpeed;
            float speedDif = targetSpeed - rbCache.velocity.x;
            float accelRate = Mathf.Abs(targetSpeed) > 0.01f ? _acceleration : _decceleration;
            float movement = Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Abs(speedDif) * accelRate, 0.9f) * Mathf.Sign(speedDif);
            rbCache.AddForce(movement * Vector2.right);
        }

        private Vector2 Project(Vector2 forward)
        {
            return forward - Vector2.Dot(forward, _normal) * _normal;
        }

        public void NormalDefinition(Collision2D collision, Vector2 cornerToClimb)
        {
            foreach (var contact in collision.contacts)
            {
                var normal = contact.normal;
                if (IsGround(normal, cornerToClimb))
                {
                    _normal = normal;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private bool IsGround(Vector2 normal, Vector2 cornerToClimb)
        {
            if (normal.x > cornerToClimb.x) return false;
            if (normal.y < cornerToClimb.y) return false;

            return true;
        }

        private float GetSpeed()
        {
            switch (typeMove) 
            { 
                case TypeMove.Walk:
                    return _walkSpeed;
                case TypeMove.Run:
                    return _runSpeed;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
        {
            NormalDefinition(collision, _cornerToClimb);
        }

        public override void Exit()
        {
            base.Exit();
            direction = 0;
            _moveSpeed = 0;
        }
    }
}

